# How to get this recursive async/await issue right?

Tags: c#, recursion, async-await

I have a recursive method that visits every node in a tree hierarchy and triggers a callback for every node, like (code below is not tested and an example):

```
void Visit(Node node, Func<Node, int> callback, CancellationToken ct)
{
  if(ct.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    return;
  }

  var processedNode = DoSomeProcessing(node);

  int result = callback(processedNode);

  // Do something important with the returned int.
  ...


  // Recursion.
  foreach(var childNode in node.Children)
  {
    Visit(childNode, callback);
  }
}
```

The method above is called from an async method that passes the callback on. As it is long running, I wrap the call into a `Task.Run()`:

```
async Task ProcessAsync(Func<Node, int> callback)
{
  var rootNode = await someWebService.GetNodes();
  await Task.Run( () => Visit(rootNode, callback) );
}
```

Now here's the issue: some async code is awaiting ProcessAsync():

```
...
await ProcessAsync( node => {
  return DoSomethingWithTheNode();
});
...
```

This works. However, no we're refactoring and `DoSomethingWithTheNode` becomes async: `DoSomethingWithTheNodeAsync`. The result won't build because the delegate types don't match. I would have to return `Task<int>` instead of `int`:

```
...

    await ProcessAsync( async node => {
      return await DoSomethingWithTheNodeAsync();
    });
    ...
```

If I change the delegate's signature to `Func<Node, Task<int>>` I will have to make my `Visit` method async which is somehow weird - it is already running as a `Task` and I don't feel very good about using a recursive async method that gets an async callback passed in. Can't explain, but it looks wrong.

Question:

- Is the approach just not suitable for an async world?
- How to get this done right?
- I originally did not want to use a callback method but an `IEnumerable<Node>`. However this seems to be impossible with async methods.
- Is this question maybe more adequate for codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Do you _need_ to be rescheduling every recursion? Was it causing performance issues with only one worker thread?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot follow. Can you be clearer what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After re-factoring, your new async `Visit` might look like this:

```
async Task Visit(Node node, Func<Node, Task<int>> callback, CancellationToken ct)
{
  if(ct.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    return;
  }

  var processedNode = DoSomeProcessing(node);

  int result = await callback(processedNode).ConfigureAwait(false);

  // Do something important with the returned int.
  ...


  // Recursion.
  foreach(var childNode in node.Children)
  {
    await Visit(childNode, callback, token);
  }
}
```

Then `ProcessAsync` would look like this:

```
async Task ProcessAsync(Func<Node, Task<int>> callback, token)
{
  var rootNode = await someWebService.GetNodes();
  await Visit(rootNode, callback, token);
}
```

And it can simply be called like this:

```
await ProcessAsync(DoSomethingWithTheNodeAsync, token);
```

**Because you are introducing asynchrony into your callback, most likely you no longer need to offload `ProcessAsync` to a separate thread.** Below I'll try to explain why.

Let's consider for a minute your `DoSomethingWithTheNodeAsync` looks like this:

```
async Task<int> DoSomethingWithTheNodeAsync(Node node)
{
    Debug.Print(node.ToString());
    await Task.Delay(10); // simulate an IO-bound operation
    return 42;
}
```

Inside `Visit`, the execution after `await callback(processedNode).ConfigureAwait(false)` will continue on a random pool thread (the thread which happened to serve the completion of the asynchronous `Task.Delay` operation). So, the UI thread will no longer be blocked.

The same is true for any other pure asynchronous API which you may be using inside `DoSomethingWithTheNodeAsync` (and which was the original reason for re-factoring, I believe).

**Now, my only concern would be this:**

```
var processedNode = DoSomeProcessing(node);
```

Once you've called `ProcessAsync(DoSomethingWithTheNodeAsync)`, the very first invocation of the above `DoSomeProcessing` will happen on the same thread as the original call. If that's a UI thread, `DoSomeProcessing` might block the UI for one time, for as as long as the processing goes inside it.

**If that's a problem, then wherever you invoke `ProcessAsync` from the UI thread, wrap it with `Task.Run`**, e.g:

```
void async button_click(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => ProcessAsync(DoSomethingWithTheNodeAsync));
}
```

Note, we still don't use `Task.Run` anywhere inside `ProcessAsync`, so there will be no redundant thread switching during the recursive traversal of the tree.

Also note, you do **not** need to add another `async/await` to the lambda like below:

```
await Task.Run(async () => await ProcessAsync(DoSomethingWithTheNodeAsync));
```

That would add some redundant compiler-generated state machine code. `Task.Run` has an override to deal with a lambda returning `Task<T>` or `Task`, which unwraps the nested task with `Task.Unwrap`. More about this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).

Finally, if something inside `DoSomeProcessing` or `DoSomethingWithTheNodeAsync` updates the UI, it has to been done on the UI thread. With Monotouch, it can be done via `SynchronizationContext.Post`/`Send` of the UI thread's `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: Great explanation. However (just for completion) if DoSomethinWithTheNodeAsync in turn calls an asynchronous method, the async has to be added to the lambda.

Comment: @Krumelur, nope :) It *may* be, but doesn't *have to* be added. Try `await Task.Run(() => ProcessAsync(DoSomethingWithTheNodeAsync))`. It will compile and work as expected, even when `DoSomethingWithTheNodeAsync` has `async` signature and uses `await` inside.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use async to unblock the calling thread, the entire call tree becomes infected up to the point where you need to release the thread. This is the nature of async, and it is a major reason why you should carefully think whether you want to bring it into a codebase or not.

In that sense, `Visit` should be async because something it calls is async. Don't fall into the trap of implementing the well-known async-over-sync anti-pattern (or sync-over-async).

Especially, this is likely to be wrong:

```
await Task.Run(() => Visit(rootNode, callback) );
```

This is async-over-sync. Make `Visit` async and treat `Task.Run` suspiciously.

Regarding your sub-question about `IEnumerable<Node>`: I'm unclear on what exactly you want to accomplish. Depending on that, you could use a `Task<IEnumerable<Node>>` or an `IAsyncEnumerable<Node>`. Depends on the use case.

> ... I will have to make my Visit method async which is somehow weird - it is already running as a Task and I don't feel very good about using a recursive async method that gets an async callback passed in.

You should feel bad about using `Task.Run`. *That's* the mistake, not making `Visit` async.

Comment: Ok. So I make `Visit` async to be able to await the callback. The fact that the whole method is recursive is not a problem? And can you be a bit more specific what's wrong with `Task.Run`? (and btw: I love your post about sorting socks! Read it already a while ago! :-))

Comment: First time I felt like a celebrity... See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx for an in-depth reasoning. There are valid use cases, but most cases aren't valid. I can answer more specifically if you tell me why you are using async in the first place. Is this a GUI app?

Comment: Yes. This is a Xamarin iOS app and the code is from a view model.