# Safe to run async delegate in synchronous method on UI?

Tags: c#, async-await

If I have an application with a synchronous method, is it safe to call an async method as shown below on a UI thread or is there an issue or potential deadlock situation? I know that calling Wait will obviously cause issues, but I feel like this may work out alright.

```
public void MyMainMethod(){
  var getResult = Task.Run(async () => { await getResultAsync(); }).Result;
  myLabel.Text = getResult;
}
```

I can successfully run on a UI thread without issue, but I feel as if I may be missing something. I understand that I could use a Task and ContinueWith, but in this example, I would want to wait for the result of the async method before exiting the synchronous method.

*Update / Clarification*

In the example above, let's assume that the MyMainMethod is an overridden method or a property, etc. and cannot be modified to be async.

Comment: I disagree with your clarification. There are ways to make `async` code work, you just need to step back and consider it a bit. If the method implementation is `async`, then the base signature should return a `Task`. I have blog entries for [`async` properties](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html) and [`async` constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html). Synchronous blocking on asynchronous code should simply not *have* to be done; there's almost always a better solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look at your code:

```
public void MyMainMethod(){
  var getResult = Task.Run(async () => { await getResultAsync(); }).Result;
  myLabel.Text = getResult;
}
```

Regardless of what's taking place inside `getResultAsync`, this code is blocking the UI thread when it calls `task.Result`. In most cases, this is already wrong.

Further, the fact that your `getResultAsync` is `async` suggests there's already an async operation inside it. There is no reason to wrap it with `Task.Run`, unless you perform a mix of CPU- and IO- bound tasks inside `getResultAsync`. Even then, it may not be necessary (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21359645/1768303) for more details).

You can control the `await` continuation context inside `getResultAsync` with `ConfiureAwait(false)`, and should do so to avoid deadlocks and redundant context switches, where possible.

So, the code can be reduced to:

```
public void MyMainMethod(){
  var getResult = getResultAsync().Result;
  myLabel.Text = getResult;
}
```

As is, it still blocks the UI. To avoid blocking, you need to make it `async`. See *Async All the Way* from [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) by Stephen Cleary.

If it *cannot* be modified to be `async` (as clarified in the update to your question), then the above is the best you can get. **Indeed, it still may cause a deadlock**, depending on what's going on inside `getResultAsync`, with out without `Task.Run`. To avoid deadlocks, you should not attempt to access the UI thread with a synchronous call like `control.Invoke` inside `getResultAsync`, or `await` any tasks scheduled on the UI thread with `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`.

However, usually it *is* possible and desirable to re-factor the code like this into an async version:

```
public async Task MyMainMethod(){
  var getResult = await getResultAsync();
  myLabel.Text = getResult;
}
```

You would be calling it from a top-level entry point of your app, like a UI event handler:

```
async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArg e)
{
    try
    {
        await MyMainMethod();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Further, the fact that your getResultAsync is async suggests there's already an async operation inside it. **There is no reason to wrap it with Task.Run**" - this is only accurate as long as `getResultsAsync` is implemented properly. If it is an `async` method which contains `await` statements without `ConfigureAwait(false)`, having `getResultsAsync` started on `TaskScheduler.Default` and unwrapped (which is what `Task.Run` does to the best of my knowledge) **may** save you from a deadlock. Otherwise good answer.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy, a good point, and [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21359645/1768303) I linked for more details indeed uses `ConfigureAwait(false)`. OTOH, if it's called as `Task.Run(lambda).Result` and anywhere inside `lambda` he does something like `control.Invoke`, **there will be a deadlock**. The bottom line, it depends on what's inside `getResultsAsync`, in any case.

Comment: I'm really surprised this only has 5 up-votes... this is one of the better explanations I've seen.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

it better to call your ui update through dispatcher.

```
 Task task = LoadTask();

 task.ContinueWith(t => 
          Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => UpdateUI()));



    public async Task LoadTask() 
    {         
       Task getdata =                
             Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>                
        {
             Sleep(3000);

        });
        await getdata;
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In most cases, I understand this is what would probably be done, but in this example, I would want to wait for the async method to complete before existing the synchronous method. I updated my example above.